# How to eliminate bounce-on-scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This [page](http://www.panix.com/~kynn/bounce-on-scroll.html) uses a bit of JS to prevent the top of the left-side panel from scrolling past the top boundary of the viewport.<sup>1</sup>

Under Chrome 31 and Firefox 25, the left-side panel remains rock-solid as one scrolls past the top of the containing div, but in other browsers (e.g. IE 11 and Safari 6) the left-side panel "bounces" vertically as one scrolls.  (Once the scrolling stops, the position of the left-side panel stabilizes.)

Here's the JS/jQuery code responsible for this effect:

```
  (function () {
     var w = $(window),
         lc = $('.left-panel');

     w.scroll(function () {
       var st = w.scrollTop(),
           ot = lc.offset().top;
       $('.vfloat').css('top', Math.max(0, st - ot));
     });

  }());
```

Question: **How can I eliminate this unwanted "bouncing" of the left-side div?**

EDIT: cleaned up and simplified the code snippet.

<sub><sup>1</sup>To make this effect possible, you may need to resize your window's vertical dimension so that enough of the right-side panel falls outside the viewport.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It is the way each browser fires scroll event. You use `height` calculations which are very expensive and cause reflows of the webpage, and it depends on browser how it handles that.

I can suggest you 2 options that will solve your problem:

1) Simply use jQuery animate to change position of your left div, that way the position will change smoothly, you can use even very fast speeds. If you don't want to use jQuery you can simulate the same behavior by writing your own code and using timers to change top position smoothly or even css3 animations.

2) The second way (and I think this is the preferred way) is not to use javascript for position manipulation in this case and use javascript only to assign `position: fixed` class to your left container on some conditions. It will still cause reflows, but you won't have such delay caused by scroll event.

Solution 1 - using css3 transition and jQuery for smooth animation: http://jsfiddle.net/6bYhx/4/ (the same can be accomplished with jQuery.animate())

Solution 2 - using `position: fixed` and `addClass` (the problem with IE still persists as scroll event is delayed): http://jsfiddle.net/S5Sgu/

So I think that the optimal solution would be smooth animation (Technique 1) with some modifications.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm interested in your solution (1).  Would you mind posting some code for it?  (Regarding solution (2): if I understand `position: fixed` correctly, it would not really replicate the desired effect, which is to allow the left-side panel to move vertically as long as its top edge remains within the viewport's top boundary.)

Comment: Minor point: After I posted the code I realized that the `height` calculations were not relevant to the question's problem (they were left over from the original code that I got this reduced example from), so I got rid of them.  I still see the same bouncing.  (This does not entirely invalidate your diagnosis; it could be that what you wrote about `height` applies to some of the other functions used in the `scroll` handler.)

Comment: @kjo Added fiddles, have a look.

Comment: @kjo Solution 2 still works better than your code, the lagging is less, but it is the best that can achieved on IE I think. Also jsFiddles don't work on my IE, and if you have the same problem, just copy the code to your local file and test it in IE.